# Apex variable usage in javascript function

Tags: apex

Can you please help me with apex variable usage in javascript function.

```
function viewattachment(expId,contTypeattch,attname){
 var  def = '{!expBlob[expId]}';
}
```

expBlob  is a Map[Id,Blob]
In the above function, I would like to query this map expBlob of the controller giving the expId. It is taking expId literally and not substituting the actual value of expId from javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54837/accessing-a-map-with-dynamic-key-a-javascript-string-valiable See if this helps you

Comment: You can go with this thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69871/access-apex-map-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access apex Map in Javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69871/access-apex-map-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because '{!expBlob[expId]}' is evaluated at page creation.
Instead you have two choices :

Either you Json.serialize your map in your controller

```
public String expBlobSerialized { get { return Json.serialize(expBlob).escapeEcmaScript(); }}
```

and then in your page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var expBlob = {!expBlobSerialized};
    function viewattachment(expId,contTypeattch,attname){
       var  def = expBlob['expId'];
    }
</script>
```

Or if your map is too big or you don't want to expose all data in the page, make a webservice and use ajax to retrieve the value you need.

Comment: Thanks, all. It is great to know how JSON is being used to consider the object as key,value and retrieve the value. Thanks for the help.